# Apple Numbers Query - Conditional Formatting

Tags: numbers

I am working on a numbers Spreadsheet that compares dates in cells. I am trying to create a condition where a date cell will turn green when the date is 3 months or more later than another date cell i.e.

```
Date 1  |  Date 2
-----------------
1/1/16  |  2/3/16
```

In this case, the second date cell would go green because it is 3 months or more outside of the first cell.

Would anyone know I can do this in Numbers?

Comment: I have worked this out by comparing the date to today's date which then goes green of past it

Comment: That is good to hear!  Congratulations.  You may wish to document your findings as an [answer and mark as answered](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) for others who may face a similar issue. Cheers!